# Cannot find my deleted answer

Tags: support, deleted-answers, undelete

I wrote an answer that I then deleted upon review that the answer was subjective and may not be technically accurate.  I would like to undelete that answer to make it unsubjective and technically valid, but now I cannot find it.  How can I locate the question containing a comment I wrote and deleted?

EDIT: I meant to refer to answer instead of comment.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot undelete a comment.

However, it might still be cached in your recent activity screen (the envelope) or clicking the activity tab on your profile (clicking your name).

If it is, just copy and paste it into the add comment box, and you are back in business.

---

If you provided an answer to a question, an then deleted it, you should be able to see it, in red, under the list of answers. You can then click the undelete button to undelete it.

Unfortunately, I do not know if deleted answers show up in any of the recent activity streams.

Comment: They do not show up, but browser history might be helpful to find the question that was answered.

Comment: I found it my browser history.