# How to find my deleted answer?

Tags: support, profile-page, deleted-answers

I answered a question and then deleted my answer. Now, I would like to find this deleted answer again. In similar posts (see [Deleted answers should get sorted at the very bottom of the answer list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20601/deleted-answers-should-get-sorted-at-the-very-bottom-of-the-answer-list), and [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43317/cannot-find-my-deleted-answer/43319#43319)) it is claimed that the deleted answers appear in the list of all answers, perhaps at the end, perhaps marked red. I checked all my answers in all possible sortings but I cannot see my deleted question, neither red nor black. So, how can I find it?

Comment: Add such questions to your Favorites, easier to track them down later.

Comment: @Shadow: yes this is theoretically possible, but still a workaround only. First, I need to do it before I delete my question, and later on I must remember that this question is favorite only because I deleted my answer to it - and I must be careful not to delete this favorite.

Comment: True, but as far as I know we can't see deleted answers anywhere except in the parent question. It has already been [suggested and declined](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/show-all-of-my-question-answers-to-me-even-if-they-are-deleted) so workaround is the only way.

Comment: @Shadow: you found an interesting page. Sounds like bad news. Thanks for your research!

Comment: Mods and pseudo-mods (10k+ rep users) can list them with the search `deleted:yes`

Answer (score 5):

Actually, [Jeff's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20601/deleted-answers-should-get-sorted-at-the-very-bottom-of-the-answer-list/51730#51730) on the first one says:

> OK, for mods and pseudo-mods (10k rep users) we now sort deleted answers to the bottom. All other user classes are unaffected.

Plus that question was talking about looking at a specific question, not your profile. And a [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43317/cannot-find-my-deleted-answer/43319#comment-97964) on the second says:

> They do not show up, but browser history might be helpful to find the question that was answered

If you can remember the question you can go there and your answer will be visible, but you can't see it in your profile. Otherwise, you might be able to get a mod to check your profile for you to find it

Comment: (1) 'All other user classes are unaffected" - what does it mean for me? (2) I have deleted my browser cache several times since then. And I do not remember the question exactly and an approximative search gives me hundreds of potential questions. I asked whether the system supports it somehow. Otherwise I could make personal notes about my activity on SO and then check these notes.

Comment: Jiri, the linked FAQ entry is (IMO), worded confusingly. Here's my understanding, which appears to be the same as Michael's. If you can find the question containing your deleted answer, you (and users with 10k+ rep) will be able to see your answer, colored with a purple background. The deleted answer is **not** visible in your profile's answer list, to you or 10k+ users (it **is** visible to moderators on that page, though - those users with diamonds besides their names).

Comment: @Michael: the problem is to find the question containing my deleted answer.

Comment: @Jiri: Yes, I know. There are only about 2^21 questions on SO, though. Grab a coffee and dig in.

Comment: this is stupid - we should be able to see our deleted answers.  i deleted one of mine and now it's impossible to find since the browser cache is gone.