# How to know which answer has been deleted and why?

Tags: support, deleted-answers

On stackoverflow.com, one of my answers got deleted (as the count got reduced by one) but I am not being able to make out that which answer has been deleted and why?

Is there any way of knowing this as it can help in improving things for future.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105835/how-to-find-my-deleted-answer

Comment: Thanks for the link Aakash, I guess this link suggests browsing through the posts and making out if the deleted answer is in the last. But, the situation is that I don't know that my which answer has been deleted and as it has been deleted now, thus I don't even have a reference too of the question at which I answered. Any suggestions on this? I was under the impression that if an answer is deleted then a message would be sent to the user but I guess that its not the case.

Comment: Oh, better: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80460/notice-of-deletion

Comment: Thanks Aakash. This link is talking exactly about what I was looking for. But I guess, that there is no decision yet on sending a notification if post is deleted. Hope this happens soon.

Comment: It won't happen. Jeff declined such feature request by himself, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/show-all-of-my-question-answers-to-me-even-if-they-are-deleted) and even 1000 upvotes won't budge Jeff once he made up his mind.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Visited the link shared by you and found this comment from Jeff - "Will not get implemented as long as I am still alive to prevent it from happening". Well, didn't know that this feature request is so 'illegal'. Sad.